Need Help from C# to VB.net Delegate Event GetInvocationList
I would like to translate code from C# to VB.Net. But I don't really understand what I can do at this point. I have 2 error messages.
"Public Event DisplayText As DisplayTextEvent" is an event and cannot be called directly. Use a RaiseEvent statement to invoke an event.
how do I translate that correctly?
C#
namespace C.I
{

    [Serializable]
    public class DisplayTextEventArgs
    {
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public TimeSpan Duration { get; set; }

        public DisplayTextEventArgs(string text, TimeSpan duration)
        {
            Text = text;
            Duration = duration;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return String.Format("{0}", Text);
        }
    }

    [Serializable]
    public delegate void DisplayTextEvent(DisplayTextEventArgs args);

    public class CaptureInterface : MarshalByRefObject
    {
        public event DisplayTextEvent DisplayText;

        private void SafeInvokeDisplayText(DisplayTextEventArgs displayTextEventArgs)
        {
            if (DisplayText == null)
                return;         //No Listeners

            DisplayTextEvent listener = null;
            Delegate[] dels = DisplayText.GetInvocationList();

            foreach (Delegate del in dels)
            {
                try
                {
                    listener = (DisplayTextEvent)del;
                    listener.Invoke(displayTextEventArgs);
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    //Could not reach the destination, so remove it
                    //from the list
                    DisplayText -= listener;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

VB.Net
Namespace C.I

    <Serializable>
    Public Class DisplayTextEventArgs
        Public Property Text As String
        Public Property Duration As TimeSpan

        Public Sub New(text As String, duration As TimeSpan)
            Me.Text = text
            Me.Duration = duration
        End Sub

        Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
            Return String.Format("{0}", Text)
        End Function
    End Class

    <Serializable>
    Public Delegate Sub DisplayTextEvent(args As DisplayTextEventArgs)

    Public Class CaptureInterface
        Inherits MarshalByRefObject

        Public Event DisplayText As DisplayTextEvent

        Private Sub SafeInvokeDisplayText(displayTextEventArgs As DisplayTextEventArgs)
            If DisplayText Is Nothing Then
                Return ' No Listeners
            End If

            Dim listener As DisplayTextEvent = Nothing
            Dim dels As [Delegate]() = DisplayText.GetInvocationList()

            For Each del As [Delegate] In dels
                Try
                    listener = CType(del, DisplayTextEvent)
                    listener.Invoke(displayTextEventArgs)
                Catch ex As Exception
                    ' Could not reach the destination, so remove it from the list
                    RemoveHandler DisplayText, listener
                End Try
            Next
        End Sub

        Public Sub DisplayTextProxyHandler(args As DisplayTextEventArgs)
            RaiseEvent DisplayText(args)
        End Sub

    End Class
End Namespace


Arguably this is a complete misuse of events and multicast delegates. You aren't supposed to use GetInvocationList in production. If you need some sort of handling of each invocation then you need an internal List(Of DisplayTextEvent)

The problem is, I don't understand the system behind it. Unfortunately I don't know how to implement this. I found it with List(of event), but I don't know how to apply it to the code. Since I'm trying to translate this code into Vb.net, I'm trying to understand what's going on. Because I understand VB.Net better. However, I'm a beginner and know a few things, but there's still a lot of background knowledge missing.

If you're not raising the event, in VB you need to refer to the hidden event field, which is the event name followed by 'Event'. (Strange - I know).
If DisplayTextEvent Is Nothing Then
    Return 'No Listeners
End If

Dim listener As DisplayTextEvent = Nothing
Dim dels() As System.Delegate = DisplayTextEvent.GetInvocationList()


OK. But what about then?
Public Event Display Text As DisplayTextEvent
is that only used here?
Public Sub DisplayTextProxyHandler(args As DisplayTextEventArgs)
RaiseEvent DisplayText(args)
End sub and that works?

That irritates me. With the names. But looks good. Thanks
